# Knockout does not trigger afterRender if collection is empty

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a Knockout template like the following, and everything works great including the **myFunction** event handler being invoked after the binding has completed - as long as the **myItems** collection has any elements.

When the view model has 0 elements in the **myItems** Collection, *afterRender* does not seem to fire.

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="template: { foreach: myItems, afterRender: myFunction }">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: $someProperty"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>                    
</table>
```

Is there any other Knockout event that can be used to invoke some logic after the view model has been databound when there is no data?

I want to be able to determine when the template is rendered, regardless of whether it has any elements.

Thanks!

Comment: The template wont render if its empty

Comment: I realize that. :) So is the common approach to have a callback for the AJAX call instead, and simply do something there if there are no items in the data received? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to simply modify the callback of the AJAX call to explicitly invoke the afterRender event handler (cleverly named *afterRender*):

```
FUNCTIONS.InvoiceList = function(target) {

    var self = this;

    self.target = target;

    self.invoices = ko.observableArray();

    self.afterRender = function() {
        $('.loading').hide();
    };

    $.getJSON("http://hostname/api/invoices", function (data) {
        self.invoices(data);

        // Invoke event handler even when there are no items
        if(data.length==0) {
           self.afterRender();
        }

    });
};
```

Comment: You can go one step forward and wrap all that logic into a reusable component i.e plugin have a look here http://knockoutjs.com/examples/grid.html

Answer (score 0):

Template is rendered container for items from your collection. If you don't have any items in your collection so there nothing to render and 'afterRender' isn't fired - it is common sense.

Could you specify what do you want to implement in this event and I try to help with way to do it.

Comment: I have a standard AJAX loader graphic spinning while data is being retrieved and rendered. Once it's complete I want to hide the graphic (as loading is complete). If there are no elements I want to notify the user about this.

Comment: if nothing is added to the container node then `afterRender` actually is fired (perhaps it didn't used to be) but the `elements[]` is empty. Disclaimer: This may just be for a true `template:` binding and not `foreach:`